# Not considering duplicate in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following schema

```
Job_ID        Date
  J1        11/1/2016
  J2        11/2/2016
```

This table is populated from script which runs daily once. The daily scripts (due to inherent design of the framework) retry the execution from beginning if they fail in between.

Because of this, i get duplicate values as :

```
Job_ID        Date
  J1        11/1/2016
  J2        11/2/2016
  J2        11/2/2016
```

I want to get the count of job id for each day, without counting the duplicate job id.

How can i do this?

Comment: Have you tried googling how to remove duplicate results? Or maybe how to COUNT DISTINCT items??

Comment: Maybe after removing dups from the data you can add a unique index on Job_ID, Date ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select date,count(job_id) from table group by date order by date
```